# dcm4che Query/Retrieve SCP

Tags: java, dcm4che

First of all, I'm new in dcm4che and without a good Documentation is difficult to begin, therefore excuse my ignorance.

I've to develop a Query/Retrieve SCP and I need to know the query parameters, in the doCFind function, entered by the SCU. 
Example:
SCU does: dcmqr MYQR@localhost:10001 -q PatientName=Manuel

How can I catch the query parameters (PatientName and Manuel) in the doCFind function?

```
protected synchronized DimseRSP doCFind(
    Association as, int pcid, DicomObject cmd,
    DicomObject keys, DicomObject rsp)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it actually like this:

```
protected DimseRSP doCFind(Association association, int i, DicomObject rq, DicomObject data, DicomObject rsp)
            throws DicomServiceException {
   String PatientsID[] = data.getStrings(Tag.PatientID);
   String PatientsName[] = data.getStrings(Tag.PatientName);
   String PatientBirthDate = data.getString(Tag.PatientBirthDate);
   String StudyDate = data.getString(Tag.StudyDate);
   String StudyTime = data.getString(Tag.StudyTime);
   String ModalitiesInStudy[] = data.getStrings(Tag.ModalitiesInStudy);
   ..... etc
}
```